# Can the author of a comment be added to the global inbox?

Tags: feature-request, comments, global-inbox, comment-replies

When another user @-mentions you in a comment this comment gets added to your inbox. The same happens when someone writes a comment to on of your posts.

Recently I knew that a certain user replied to me, but I wasn't exactly sure what their comment was, and to what post their comment was exactly. So I was looking in my global inbox to try and find the specific comment by looking for the comment authors. Unfortunately that information isn't present in the inbox.

[image: Screenshot of the global inbox showing several comments and one chat ping. The chat ping starts with the username of the user that wrote the message.]

As you can see this information is present for a chat reply. It starts with the username of the user that wrote the message.

**Can we add the author's name to a comment in the (global) inbox?** 
This makes it easier to find a certain comment when you recall a certain person replied, but can't recall exactly where.

Comment: Yeah, it already exists for chat messages, so should just be applied to comments as well, the infrastructure is already there.

Comment: I actually found another (highly-upvoted) feature request from several years earlier that this is a duplicate of, so I'm removing the [status-review] tag from this post and closing it as a duplicate of that one – then I'll add the [status-review] tag to that post instead.